# How to make the transitions in my css work

Tags: jquery, html, css

See fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/whvSL/8/

I want to keep my css transitions in my css.file and not apply any transitions with jQuery directly. This is so that I keep the code clean and there is a clear overview.

I have read probably more than 10 blogs on this subject and checked a multitude of stackoverflow answers that explain how to get this done, but yet I can't seem to get it work for me. Therefor please do not send me more documentation on how transitions work in general or links to other stackoverflow pages where they explain this, because it doesn't help me at this stage.

I need to know where exactly the transitions go in de css.
Why they go there and why my version is not working.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
You `.mouseenter` over a sidebar and that sidebar **slowly** turns coloured / The feathers inside that sidebar **slowly** turn coloured and the text as well.

The effect of becoming coloured from being gray is already in there. I just need to know where the transition code goes including all possible verdor prefixes.

Right now it is changing from gray to coloured as it should. But I want this effect to take place **slowly!!**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please break this down in a smaller example, e.g. only one link? Also, please post [the relevant parts of] your code directly in the question as well.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery at all? Just use the `:hover` pseude class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close- if I just add the `hColor` class, which has all of the `transition` properties, to the elements you're adding/removing classes from, it works:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/whvSL/9/

Hover over the top area ("About") to see it.

The transition properties just need to be on the element that's being transitioned.

Comment: Can you please tell me which lines in which files you edited?
Thx

Comment: I added "hColor" to the HTML in a couple places. I don't think you had  that in the HTML before, so just search for it.

Comment: I would probably change the declaration on line `73` of your CSS to affect `.bar, .text, .feathers` - that should work without changing any of your HTML.

Comment: Got it! 
I knew I was very close to resolving this, but believe it or not, I as stuck with this or a few days. Thx!

Comment: How would you exactly change it?

Comment: I told you exactly how I would change it. You want the transitions to always happen on `.bar`, `.text`, and `.feathers`- so you should make a rule in your CSS that applies to those, and put the transition properties there. This is the same as if you wanted to make those elements all have a border or be red or something.

Comment: I understand the theory behind it, but I was referring to the code. 
If it's not too much trouble for, can you please provide me the code?